# ag-grid change from rowModelType before sorting

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid-community v19.1.4. I have huge data (in the order of 10 million rows and 30 columns per row), so I have rowModelType set to 'infinite'. I want to sort the columns. For some columns I have client-side translation enabled and that prevents from using server-side sorting.

So I want to from 'infinite' to 'clientSide' rowModelType.

Is there a hook available in ag-grid, which can help me change rowModelType after a column header is clicked for sorting and before the actual sorting is performed?

In the worst case I can add a button which can flip between 'infinite' and 'clientSide' rowModelTypes, but that would be really the worst  option. So I am hoping there is something more elegant way of achieving this.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), or maybe just a poorly explained question. With ag-grid, you set the row model at the start and generally never change it. What is this "client-side translation"?

Comment: By "client-side translation" I mean, I am using pascalprecht.translate to translate the contents of the cells. Since this can only be done at client-side, I want to change the rowModelType to 'clientSide' for sorting data.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question, there's not enough detail or code. You *might* want to generate the response locally instead of requesting new data from the server (shim the request), if sorting on that column. But that sounds broken, what if different rows out of your 10 million should actually be shown?

Comment: By default, the rows will be fetched in infinite roeModelType, so a subset of rows are fetched from server. I only need to be able to sort the ones currently fetched. So now I want to do client side sorting on the fetched.

Comment: That's why I want to know if there's a way by which I can change the rowModelType when a column header is clicked for sorting.